# Repeated measures mixed model correlation between measurements

Tags: correlation, mixed-model, time-varying-covariate, bland-altman-plot

I am interested in looking at the correlation between two types of heart function measurements over time. `test1` can be considered the true value. The true value (`test1`) changes over time, but not much whereas `test2` changes a lot.

The hypothesis is that the two tests have a good correlation in the beginning, and then the new type of measurement (`test2`) loses its ability to follow `test1`, but I need to quantify it somehow.

I was thinking of some way of measuring if `test2` becomes less correlated with `test1` at each time point. Maybe using the correlation at baseline as a reference.
I have four distinct measuring `time` points (factor), my `testtype` (2 types) as factor and my output (`value`) is continuous on both test 1 and 2 but very different scales. Finally, I would use the `subject` (ID) for the random effect.
So my idea was to do a mixed model like this (using `R`):

```
lme(value ~ time * testtype, random = ~ 1 | subject, data = df, na.action = na.omit)
```

My output would then be estimates for test overall, `time1` vs `time2`, `time1` vs `time3` etc. And finally `test1:time2`, `test1:time3`, etc.

My question is can I use this method to evaluate if the correlation between tests is different at different `time` points?

And how do I turn the estimates with standard error into something meaningful? 
Something I can interpret as "the correlation between tests at `time2` was xx lower than at `time1`."

EDIT: Using Dimitris model I get a correlation structure like this:

```
             1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
1 1.0000000 0.2868521 0.2868521 0.2868521 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987
2 0.2868521 1.0000000 0.2868521 0.2868521 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987
3 0.2868521 0.2868521 1.0000000 0.2868521 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987
4 0.2868521 0.2868521 0.2868521 1.0000000 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987
5 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987 1.0000000 0.6351789 0.6351789 0.6351789
6 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.6351789 1.0000000 0.6351789 0.6351789
7 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.6351789 0.6351789 1.0000000 0.6351789
8 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.1973987 0.6351789 0.6351789 0.6351789 1.0000000
```

EDIT 2
For Dimitri - Here is the output from getVarCov(fm)

```
Marginal variance covariance matrix
        1       2       3       4       5       6       7
1 133.240  38.220  38.220  43.692  43.692  43.692  43.692
2  38.220 133.240  38.220  43.692  43.692  43.692  43.692
3  38.220  38.220 133.240  43.692  43.692  43.692  43.692
4  43.692  43.692  43.692 367.700 233.550 233.550 233.550
5  43.692  43.692  43.692 233.550 367.700 233.550 233.550
6  43.692  43.692  43.692 233.550 233.550 367.700 233.550
7  43.692  43.692  43.692 233.550 233.550 233.550 367.700
  Standard Deviations: 11.543 11.543 11.543 19.175 19.175 19.175 19.175
```

Comment: It is doable by fitting mixed model. But it is very complicated. You need to find a person who can write down $Y, X, Z, G, R$ matrices which are used in mixed model before fitting the mixed model.

Comment: Do the two tests measure the same thing? I.e., is the `value` from test1 the same outcome as the `value` from test2?

Comment: The two tests represent the output from the heart, but not directly so one is mililiter blood pumped out and the other is difference in heart chamber size at maximum and minimum - so a percentage of how much the heart contracts. contracts.

Comment: @a_statistician - Would it be better to split my data into 4 so I only analyze 1 timepoint at a time?

Comment: No. Should fit one model to answer all of questions in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments above, it seems that the two tests are measuring two different related outcomes. Hence, it would make more sense to fit a bivariate mixed model, in which you account that the error variance is different for the two tests. You could fit this model using something like this:

```
fm <- lme(value ~ 0 + testtype + testtype:time, data = df, na.action = na.omit,
          random = ~ 0 + testtype + testtype:time | subject,
          weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | testtype))

summary(fm)
```

The coefficients you will obtain will be per test-type. Regarding the correlations, you can use

```
V <- getVarCov(fm, type = "marginal", individual = 1)
R <- cov2cor(V[[1]])
R
```

This will give you the marginal covariance matrix `V` of the two outcomes per test (i.e., it will be an $8 \times 8$ matrix), which we turn to the corresponding correlation matrix `R`. The two block-diagonal parts (i.e., `R[1:4, 1:4]` and `R[5:8, 5:8]`) will be the correlations over time within the same test. The part `R[1:4, 5:8]` will be the correlation between the tests over time. *Note:* you will need to select an individual in the `individual` argument that has all eight measurements.

However, just my 2c, I don't think correlations are easier to interpret than the coefficients.

Comment: just to be sure, when you write `testtype:type`is that `testtype:time`?

Comment: Yes, my mistake.

Comment: So when I look at the output I first get the fixed effect values for `test 1` and `test 2` and then for `test1:time1`, `test2:time1`, `test1:time2`etc. So how do you understand these fixed effects?

Comment: I added the correlation structure in the original post. Because when you say that block R[1:4,5:8] is the correlation between tests over time I am puzzled because the correlation is constant over time. So what if the correlation changes between time 3 and 4  but not 1 and 2?

Comment: Is the model fitted with `random = ~ 1 | subject` or `random = ~ 0 + testtype + testtype:time | subject`? Could you perhaps also show what the output of `getVarCov(fm)` is, i.e., without specifying the `type` argument.

Comment: I added the getVarCov output in the original post. The model looks like this: `fm<-lme(value~0+testtype+testtype:time, data=df, na.action=na.omit,
+              random= ~0+testtype+testtype|subject ,
+              weights=varIdent(form=~1|testtype))`

Comment: The random argument is not the same as in my code as far as I can see...

Comment: You're right. My mistake. I just corrected it but then I get the warning iteration limit reached without convergence (10)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84673/discussion-between-dimitris-rizopoulos-and-lars-g).