# rmcorr package with changing correlations

Tags: r, correlation, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I was looking at the rmcorr package in r for repeated measures correlation and have read the paper on it:   Bakdash JZ, Marusich LR. Repeated Measures Correlation. Front Psychol. 2017;8:456. Published 2017 Apr 7. doi:10.3389/fpsyg.2017.00456

My question is - if the measures you are comparing have shifting correlations so the first time you measure the correlation is high, but the 2nd or 3rd time the correlation is low will this model give you an average correlation across time?

I have the situation where 2 measures are correlated at first but drift away from eachother over time and I want to be able to quantify either their correlation over time and I still haven't come up with a useful way to do it.  (see previous question [Repeated measures mixed model correlation between measurements](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372385/repeated-measures-mixed-model-correlation-between-measurements/372530?noredirect=1#comment700357_372530))

Comment: You could start looking at `coplot`, there is some simulated example here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203494/can-i-analyze-or-model-a-conditional-correlation/368228#368228.  Could you post or link to your data?